# Changing MongoDB location in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

By default MongoDB save location (where the actual database will be) is `/data/db` (on Windows at least). But I'd like to change the location for a certain Node.js application, to say `nodeapproot/data/db` instead using Node.js itself. I don't know if it's possible, but if it is, I'd appreciate some help with how to achieve that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your work and tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: That's just it, haven't tried anything because haven't found anything to try. I found out how to do it with SQlite, but not with MongoDB. Oh and, thanks :)

Comment: MongoDB ultimately should be run as a service on Windows so you wouldn't normally have a "per application" configuration (it's a lot more convenient setup that way too). You'd need to run `mongod` manually for your app. A single service can have multiple named databases.

Comment: You might have a point there @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did u try this command to change dbpath

C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath d:\test\mongodb\data

Just create new folder and change path to it

Source : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Comment: That works, not quit what I wanted, but does what I asked. Thank you.